# Huge memory consumption of UniversalImageLoader

Tags: android, memory, android-scrollview, universal-image-loader, outofrangeexception

I have a problem using the Universal Image Loader Library.
Unfortunately, the Library causes huge memory usage of my application.

I have a ScrollView (there are tons of reasons why I am using a ScrollView instead of a ListView, most of them have to do with custom insertion and item selection animations) holding about **20 custom Views**.
Each of those custom views consists of some TextViews as well as an ImageView.

And now here is the thing:

The Images dispalyed in the ImageViews are downloaded from the Internet and all have around **100-150kb (dimension 640 x 320)** each. If I download the Images using the UniversalImageLoader my app crashes with an OutOfMemoryException because it uses around **80Mb** of memory.

If I do not download the Images, and just put in a Hard-Coded Image with the size of **1200kb (dimension 1920 x 1080)** per custom view, my app only consumes around **40Mb** of memory.

What am I doing wrong using the UniversalImageLoader when downloading **ten times smaller Images causes my app to use up twice as much memory?**

I disabled all caching mechanisms but the problem still persists.

Here is my UniversalImageLoader setup:

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c)
        .build();

ImageLoader.getInstance().init(config);

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()
        .showStubImage(R.drawable.loading)
        .showImageForEmptyUri(R.drawable.loading)
        .showImageOnFail(R.drawable.loading)
        .cacheInMemory(false)
        .cacheOnDisc(false)
        .imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.IN_SAMPLE_INT) // default
        .build();
```

And in code, I call it like this:

```
ImageLoader im = ImageLoader.getInstance();
im.displayImage("myurl", myimageview, options);
```

**What am I doing wrong? Why is the UniversalImageLoader using up so much memory?**

Comment: File size is often not the same as size in memory when talking about images. I'm guessing your 100-150KB numbers refer to file size (compressed).

Comment: Yes, when I download the files for example via my browser on the computer, they are all between 100 and 150Kb. So I rly dont get it why the 100-150KB images use up more memory than the 1200Kb images. It must have something to do with the ImageLoader and its caching.

Comment: Again, compression... Pixel size is what matters here.

Comment: Tell us the *dimension* (i.e. 1920x1080) of the images you are using for both scenarios, otherwise no one can help you on this.

Comment: I edited my question with the dimensions. Thank you. They are 640 x 320 for the downloaded images (having 150kb) and 1920 x 1080 for the hard coded Image (having 1200kb).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For all the other people out there having the same issues:

**I managed to minimize my Memory usage and get rid of the OutOfMemoryException** by following these guidelines:

> https://github.com/nostra13/Android-Universal-Image-Loader#useful-info

The most important part for me was to reduce the ThreadPoolSize down to 2. **I could not feel any performance changes after setting it down.**

```
ImageLoaderConfiguration config = new ImageLoaderConfiguration.Builder(c)
.threadPoolSize(2) 
.build();

DisplayImageOptions options = new DisplayImageOptions.Builder()

// other options

.bitmapConfig(Bitmap.Config.RGB_565)
.imageScaleType(ImageScaleType.EXACTLY)

// other options
.build();
```

This reduced my applications total memory consumption by about 35%.